# How to prevent Minecraft griefing in Bukkit

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I know it's there somewhere, but I cannot find it. A couple of years ago I was playing on an MC server where there was a good solution to prevent griefing. The method worked in the way that if a player places a block the other players cannot destroy that block and give a red message saying that they don't have permissions.

I've installed a Bukkit server with plugins "world-edit, world-guard, PermissionsEx". I need to put the block ID in somewhere but I don't know how.

I only need help setting up the block IDs to work with the plugins. I've already chosen the plugins I want to use and don't need recommendations.

Comment: @Topcode This isn't a recommendation as far as I can see because the asker already has chosen what plugins they want to use, they just need help setting it up. If they were asking which plugin they should use then it is off-topic but they are not.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 i see.

Comment: Numeric IDs haven't been a thing since 1.12

Comment: Only preventing destroying blocks? Highways on 2b2t were griefed by bots placing millions of obsidian blocks.

Answer (score 1):

A method of mitigating griefing is keeping a history of the world. The simplest way is to regularly backup the world. However, there is an automated way to do it using [LogBlock](https://www.iani.de/jenkins/job/LogBlock/).

If you have [WorldEdit](https://builds.enginehub.org/job/worldedit?branch=master) installed, you can select a region and rollback a section of the world, undoing any griefing that has happened.